# What is this perl code comparing files actually doing?

Tags: perl

I have seen this perl one-liner, that is supposedly comparing two files.

However, I am looking at it for some time and I still have no idea what is it doing,  what is the `.=` operator doing there, why is there a regexp for ending with 10 of all things,  what are we doing with the `@ARGV`.

The one-liner is

```
perl -ne 'print if ($seen{$_} .= @ARGV) =~ /10$/'  file1 file2
```

and I found it here

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/command-to-display-lines-common-in-files/

Comment: @KarelBílek Why did you flag/VTC your own question as a duplicate 1 minute after posting it, instead of just deleting it?

Comment: I was not sure what is the correct procedure, if deleting or self-flagging as duplicate. I unfortunately found it only after posting.

Comment: I can still delete it.

Comment: I was just curious. It's probably fine to leave it, once it's closed as a dupe it will maintain a nice flow of google juice to the other question.